# Unit Testing Code Coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

I am becoming a little confused about code coverage.

Example:
I have a method that has multiple if statements (Not nested), each one appending to a string that I return once done.

My unit test just checks the initial and end result, something I'm purposely doing for the sake of this question. Nothing in between (so no checking the else statements)

Problem:
If I run that test, I get 100% code coverage. The problem I'm having in understanding this is that I want the code coverage of the method itself, not how much of my test is being hit. It should be a bit lower since the else statements haven't been hit.

I've looked over a various tutorials and the msdn about unit testing and code coverage. In some cases the tests appear to be analysing the code from the method itself (what I want to do) but in most other cases it checks just the test for the code coverage.

My question is; 
Is there a way to link up a test to a method so it gets code coverage of the method when I analyse the tests code coverage, or is this what code coverage is meant to do and the user has to write the tests to account for these branches?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Code example.

```
public static string testingString(string s1, string s2, bool isAllowed, bool isAdmin, bool isCustomer){
    string result = string.Format("{0}/{1}", s1, s2);
    if (isAllowed) result += "/Allowed";
    if (isAdmin) result += "/admin";
    if (isCustomer) result += "/customer";
    return result;
}
```

Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void testingString_BasicTest()
{
    var result = testingString("test1", "test2", false, false, false);
    var expectedResult = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "test1", "test2");

    Debug.WriteLine("Result should be: " + expectedResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, url);
}
```

testingString_BasicTest will have 100% code coverage in this scenario, despite not hitting the 3 if statements results.

Comment: A code example may help here :)

Comment: This gets 100% code coverage?  [You actually ran this using the coverage tool and looked at the report?] Using what tool [presumably VS2013]?   It might get 100% *line* coverage; every *line* in your function is executed.  But it is clear that not every *statement* is executed.  With false/false/false, the   "result += ...." statements are obviously NOT executed.

Comment: ... one also needs to watch out for tool limitations.   Many byte-code instrumenters can only resolve code down to the "line" level, because the byte code at best tracks line numbers.   A "statement coverage" tool that tracks statements by *line* may in fact confusing report that "line" is entirely covered, if any part of any statement in the line gets executed.  One needs a tool with finer granularity to report statement coverage if there are multiple statements in a line, and you want to be able to tell them apart.

Comment: `testingString_BasicTest` will show 100% code coverage because each line of your test has executed.  That isn't important.  What is important is the code coverage shown for `testingString`  For that method you should see about 50% code coverage with the test you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code coverage refers to the execution of the code from within the test execution.  It doesn't actually have anything to do with what is tested, just that it is executed at some point while your tests are running.

Code coverage will return 100% if every command in that method is executed at any point during your testing process.  If you want to review the code coverage (using the VS 2013 Ultimate code coverage tool) for an individual test, selected it in the Test Manager window and click Test/Analyze Code Coverage/Selected Tests to see what that particular test covers.

Comment: This answer is extremely misleading; it assumes "code coverage" === "line coverage".  There are lots of kinds of test coverage; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage for the most commonly used terms.  What OP wants is something more like "statement coverage".

Comment: The statement "Code coverage will return 100% if every command in that method is executed at any point during your testing process." is meant to convey that every statement on every line is touched, not just that every line is touched.  None of the code-coverage tools I am familiar with will indicate 100% code coverage without every statement being executed.

Answer (score -1):

Given your update you are getting 100% coverage because of the way you have structured your code. All lines are hit, event though not all code paths are executed. If you restructure your code like this then you won't get 100% coverage anymore:

```
public static string testingString(string s1, string s2, bool isAllowed, bool isAdmin, bool isCustomer){
    string result = string.Format("{0}/{1}", s1, s2);
    if (isAllowed) 
    {
        result += "/Allowed";
    }
    if (isAdmin) 
    {
        result += "/admin";
    }
    if (isCustomer) 
    {
        result += "/customer";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Some tools will handle this better than others (I believe JetBrains dotCover would not report your version as covered) but some just look at whether the code executed was on a line or not, as it appears the visual studio tool is doing, so it see the `if()` being executed and considers the whole line being covered.

Comment: This is forcing seperate statements on seperate lines, thus attempting to make "line coverage"  === " statement coverage".   I don't know if this actually succeeds with the MS tool; are the "{" and ""}" also marked as line-covered?  (The standard PHP tool using XDebug suffers from the same problem of not being able to count line-coverage for "}", also because it only has access to "line numbers" and the "}" isn't in the byte code).